# vim - Ignore timoutlen for certain key-mapping macros

Tags: vim

I have made two simple `nmap`s in Vim that moves the cursor 10 times right and left by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>z</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd>

```
nmap <ESC>z 10l
nmap <ESC>Z 10h
```

It works perfect.

Now I would like to add two similar `nmap`s that delete 10 times

```
nmap d<ESC>z 10x
nmap d<ESC>Z 10X
```

This works almost fine, and follows the vim logic of operation followed by cursor move.

Unfortunately it times out if I don't press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>z</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> quickly after <kbd>d</kbd>.
I find this odd, because I have not mapped anything to just <kbd>d</kbd>. And if I press <kbd>w</kbd> or <kbd>W</kbd> after <kbd>d</kbd>, I can wait as long as I want.

I know there's a special thing about built-in maps such ad `dw` and `dW`.

To my question: Is there a way I can get my own `nmap`s to accept long delays between the key-presses?

Comment: in you mapping you have `<ESC>z` but in your text you say `Alt-z`. Which one do you use?

Comment: That's the same. `Alt-z` sends an `Esc` followed by a `z`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that by default, `'timeoutlen'` (default 1 s) applies to mapped keys. I find this useful, but if you really want your started mappings to wait indefinitely, you have to define the map **on the first key only, then query and handle the remaining keys yourself**.

```
function! MapOrDefault()
    let c = nr2char(getchar())
    return c == "\<A-z>" ? '10x' : 'd' . c
endfunction
nnoremap <expr> d MapOrDefault()
```

Note: Though it's technically equivalent, I'd recommend to prefer the Vim key-notation (`<A-z>`) instead of the cryptic `<Esc>z`.

Note: [You should use `:noremap`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html); it makes the mapping immune to remapping and recursion.

Comment: Thanks. That was useful. Only problem is that <A-z> is two chars, but I can just parse one char at a time.

Comment: Look at my example; it's just one character, represented by the key input sequence `<Esc>` + `z`. At least in my GVIM, it is handled correctly as one. If not, you'll need to detect `<Esc>`, and then get the next one with another `getchar()`.